# Ruby on Rails -- independant controller method for static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, routes, controllers

So basically I want to use a simple controller method with no params:

```
def create_message
   @a = Message.create(:body => "Hello")
   @a.save
   redirect_to messages_path
end
```

but i'm routing from the home page, pages controller:

```
def home
end
```

I'm having a problem figuring out what to write in the routes file, I've tried almost everything including but not limited to:

```
resources :pages do
  collection do
   get :create_message
  end
end
```

Views:

```
<%= link_to "Create Message", create_message_pages_path, class:"btn btn-primary"%>
```

Error:

```
The action 'create_message' could not be found for PagesController
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @IgorDrozdov the error I get is: The action 'create_message' could not be found for PagesController

Comment: @J.Foe you need to define the `create_message` method in your `PagesController`

Comment: @MrYoshiji it is in the pages_controller

Comment: I highly doubt that. If the path is not known by Rails router, you will get a `Routing Error`. If the path can be resolved by Rails router, but the action is not defined in the proper controller, it will raise a `<action> could not be found for <Controller>` error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom route for `create_message` like this

```
#routes.rb    
get 'create_message' => 'pages#create_message', as: 'create_message'
```

Then `link_to` would be:

```
#view
<%= link_to "Create Message", create_message_path, class:"btn btn-primary"%>
```

Comment: I still get the same error: The action 'create_message' could not be found for PagesController

Comment: is create_message defined **in** pages_controller.rb ?

Comment: In  which controller is the 'create_message' action?

Comment: @meshin pages_controller.rb

Comment: I put the method in another controller and for some reason it worked......can anyone explain that

Comment: Can you run this in the terminal in the root of your rails app to see all the routes 'rake routes' an post here the results

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem once, in my case it is defining action under private block of controller gave the "The Action could not be found error". From your question I see there is no problem in defining routes and using it in view file. Please check to see if the create_message action is defined under private block in pages_controller.rb file. Hope it helps.